# How to stream to multiple destinations with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, ubuntu-16.04

I want to stream my video to 4 destinations. My input signal needs to be recoded to "H.264 AAC", so I want to send it to my server. This works already.

```
Client -> Server with ffmpeg -> Destinations
```

Now I have a performance problem: One should get the stream in 1080p and two in 720p.

So it would make sense to first get the stream in the desired formats H.264 1080p and AAC with 30 FPS and then calculate the stream once, send it 1:1 to the two HD targets.

and create a 720p stream in parallel and send it to the two remaining destinations.

What is the best way to do this on a **Ubuntu 16.04 machine**?

My previous approach:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://livestream.domain.example/live/<key> \
-threads 2 -s hd1080 -preset veryfast -f flv rtmp://destination1.example/live2/<key> \
-threads 2 -s hd1080 -preset veryfast -f flv rtmp://destination2.example/live2/<key> \
-threads 1 -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 3000k -f flv rtmp://destination3.example/x/<key> \
-threads 1 -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -f flv 'rtmps://destination4.exmple/rtmp/<key>'
```

You can see the repetitions in the code. :-/

Answer (score 3):

Use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee):

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://livestream.domain.example/live/<key> \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:1080,fps=30,split=outputs=2[1080a][1080b];[0:v]scale=-2:720,fps=30,split=outputs=2[720a][720b]" \
-map "[1080a]" -map "[1080b]" -map "[720a]" -map "[720b]" -map 0:a \
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -g 60 -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -f tee \
"[select=\'v:0,a\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://destination1.example/live2/<key>| \
 [select=\'v:1,a\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://destination2.example/live2/<key>| \
 [select=\'v:2,a\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://destination3.example/live2/<key>| \
 [select=\'v:3,a\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://destination4.example/live2/<key>"
```